# Successive Shortest Paths vs Ford–Fulkerson

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, max-flow

Can someone explain how exactly Successive Shortest Paths (SSP) is a generalization of the Ford–Fulkerson algorithm? I've found this stated in a few papers and websites as well as the Wikipedia page for the [Minimum-cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). But none of them go any further than that statement or explain how exactly they differ. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.